# CMakeLists.txt How to enable --prefix installation path

Tags: c++, cmake

I have followed the [CMake Tutorial - Step 4: Installing and Testing](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Installing%20and%20Testing.html)
and everything worked fine until I needed to pass the `--prefix` argument to my script.
I use Ubuntu 20.01 and Visual Studio Code with the CMakeTool extension.
If I config build and install my app from the CMakeTool extension shortcut command by invoking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> Visual Studio Studio Code options, everything works as expected, but if I repeat same command in Visual Studio Code's terminal with `--prefix`/`-target` options, it points to another location and I get errors.

```sh
/usr/bin/cmake --build /mnt/Pliki_Mic/C++/Ncurses/build --config Debug --target "/home/mic/Ncurses" install -j 10 --
error: unknown target '/home/mic/Ncurses'
```

And another:

```sh
cmake --install . --prefix "/home/mic/Ncurses"
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Up-to-date: /mnt/Pliki_Mic/C++/Ncurses/build/bin/ncurses
-- Up-to-date: /mnt/Pliki_Mic/C++/Ncurses/build/bin/include/TutorialConfig.h
-- Up-to-date: /mnt/Pliki_Mic/C++/Ncurses/build/bin/lib/libMathFunctions.a
-- Up-to-date: /mnt/Pliki_Mic/C++/Ncurses/build/bin/include/MathFunction.h
```

But it wont produce a binary in the expected 'prefixed' directory.
And here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name and version
project(ncurses VERSION 1.0)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# should we use our own math functions
option(USE_MYMATH "Use ncurses provided math implementation" ON)

# configure a header file to pass some of the CMake settings
# to the source code
configure_file(TutorialConfig.h.in TutorialConfig.h)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
# add the MathFunctions library
if(USE_MYMATH)
    add_subdirectory(MathFunctions)
    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS MathFunctions)
endif()

# add the executable
add_executable(ncurses tutorial.cxx)

target_link_libraries(ncurses PUBLIC ${EXTRA_LIBS})

# add the binary tree to the search path for include files
# so that we will find TutorialConfig.h
target_include_directories(ncurses PUBLIC
                            "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"                           
                            )
install(TARGETS ncurses DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
#install(TARGETS ncurses DESTINATION  /home/mic/Ncurses)
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/TutorialConfig.h"
            DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/include
        )

enable_testing()

# does the application run
add_test(NAME Runs COMMAND ncurses 25)
        
# does the usage message work?
add_test(NAME Usage COMMAND ncurses)
set_tests_properties(Usage
    PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "Usage:.*number"
    )
        
# define a function to simplify adding tests
function(do_test target arg result)
    add_test(NAME Comp${arg} COMMAND ${target} ${arg})
    set_tests_properties(Comp${arg}
        PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION ${result}
        )
    endfunction(do_test)
        
# do a bunch of result based tests
do_test(ncurses 4 "4 is 2")
do_test(ncurses 9 "9 is 3")
do_test(ncurses 5 "5 is 2.236")
do_test(ncurses 7 "7 is 2.645")
do_test(ncurses 25 "25 is 5")
do_test(ncurses -25 "-25 is [-nan|nan|0]")
do_test(ncurses 0.0001 "0.0001 is 0.01")
```

Comment: More than --prefix problem I got another. That CMakeLists.txt don't product proper binary witch using my implementation of sqrt() function like in tutorial even if USE_MYMATH option is set to ON

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
install(TARGETS ncurses DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
```

Prefix comes from the user. You do not know it.

Use relative paths.

```
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/TutorialConfig.h"
        DESTINATION bin/include
    )
```

Will install at `<prefix>/bin/include`. Read `install` documentation https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html .

Comment: Can you specify all command ? Did you mean I should use --prefix=/pat/to/dir/ argument in /usr/bin/cmake --build /mnt/Pliki_Mic/C++/Ncurses/build --config Debug --target install  -j 10 command or it is different argument ? If yes it dont work. I also trying add path after target  and after install - nothingk happend except error mesasage.

Comment: `all command` for? Installation would be with `cmake --install . --prefix "/home/mic/Ncurses"`, just like you did.

Comment: It won't compile the binary, error seds that is no relevant path even if so.

Comment: No, it won't - installation is not building. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#manual:cmake(1)

Comment: Yes it is, I use vsc cli and Cmake tools configure command before. Sam set of command install and build binary as expect. But it won't use my version of math function as I mentioned. Or my thinking is wrong and I don't understand what you exactly mean.

Comment: It install only headers in prefix directory so it seems to do the thing expect in documentation, not what I want. Tommorow I read the man page witch you send.